# Programatically search npm registry for package

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to search in the *npm* registry for packages from my node app, but I couldn't find a documented/official way to search programatically. Of course I could just use `https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=`, but I rather not parse the HTML you'll get in return.

Is there a way to search the npm registry and get a JSON in return? Or do I have to use a third-party site, like `https://api.npms.io/v2/search`?

Comment: Have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071621/query-npmjs-registry-via-api

Comment: Only if the answer is that there is no such option :-/

Comment: You can search for a particular package - https://replicate.npmjs.com/"package-name". This returns a json, as you wanted. Similarly, for all_docs - https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs?include_docs=true gives you a json containing the docs of all of the packages. Also look at the question @styopdev provided, which gives more information.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much info you need, `https://www.npmjs.com/search/suggestions?q=` might be enough.

Example: https://www.npmjs.com/search/suggestions?q=koa