# Downloading entire NPM package list

Tags: npm

This question is NPM specific.

Few years ago I wrote a tool named `qnp` that downloads entire list of npm packages and then executes local queries very fast, like 0.2 second per query. This allows to perform a very interesting study of the modern programming world, filtering by author names, descriptions, tags, etc, doing hundreds of queries, inspecting results, analyzing, having ideas, doing more queries. An official client is good, but does not allow you to do very fast queries at the speed of thought. Here is my question:

About a year ago the location of the registry metadata DB of NPM was abandoned, now it returns an empty file. How can I download/fetch the entire list of metadata now? I need at least those fields: title/author/description/keywords/date. Optionally downloads count, dependencies list, version.

Here is the code that was working previously:

```
   var request  =  http.get({
         host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
         path: '/-/all/static/all.json',
         headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
         }
      }, function (a,b,c) {
      var done  =  0 ; var all  =  parseInt(a.headers['content-length'])
      a.on('data', function (a,b,c) {
         done += a.length
         process.stdout.write( '\r' + (done / (all/100)).toFixed(2)+'%  ' )
      })
      console.log('download started') 
      a.pipe(S)
      S.on('finish', function (a,b,c) {
         console.log('download complete') 
         S.close(f)
      })
   })
```

Comment: In this npm [blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/157615772423/deprecating-the-all-registry-endpoint) post it recommends using  `/-/v1/search` and provides further details for that endpoint [here](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md). Also refer to the paragraph in the blog post where it encourages you to write a [registry follower](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/follower.md) as this may be pertinent to your requirement.

Comment: f.y.i - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251633/list-all-public-packages-in-the-npm-registry#answer-48272170)

Comment: My apologies; I missed this existing question when I posted my [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48251633/1709587) yesterday. Since I've now got an answer there - linked to by @RobC - perhaps we should close this question as a duplicate of mine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all public packages in the npm registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251633/list-all-public-packages-in-the-npm-registry)

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545387/5923666)

Answer (score 1):

Since this post came up near the top when I searched for the answer, let me point out two packages that might be helpful for people landing on this old question:

- https://github.com/nice-registry/all-the-package-names
- https://github.com/bconnorwhite/all-package-names

Using the first one, I downloaded a list with 2.247.694 entries by using

```bash
pnpx all-the-package-names > ~/temp/all-the-package-names.txt
```

where `pnpx` is `pnpm`'s equivalent to `npx`, the npm CLI runner (the latter installed with NodeJS).