# How to find reverse devDependency (dependents) of NPM package

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json

There was similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923195/how-to-find-reverse-dependencies-on-npm-package) seeking clarification on how to find reverse dependency or dependents for a given NPM package. npmjs dot com even has a tab showing such dependencies:

[image]

**However, this does not show the dependents if the dependency type is devDependency**

**Do we have any alternative service/website that reflects the dependents?**

Further Context for the question: I am authoring a package which is expected mostly to be used as devDependency. However, I do not get any visibility on who might be using my package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find reverse dependencies on npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923195/how-to-find-reverse-dependencies-on-npm-package)

Comment: There's nothing that already exists AFAIK. Consider building your own tool that infers this information from data (i.e. JSON) held in the npm registry. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251633/list-all-public-packages-in-the-npm-registry) that describes how to gain access to the JSON data. Then use something like node.js to parse it, and infer the information as necessary to meet your requirement.