# npm package metadata api

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-registry

npm says we can able to get the metadata of the package, with the public api provided below

https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REPLICATE-API.md#get

https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#get-all

but none of them seems to work when we call the api from the external web app(assume localhost). it gives the cors eror.

only the search api seems to be public

https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#get-v1search

can anyone help me finding the public api, from which we can retrieve the metadata of the package. without giving the cors error.

i have also used the techniques which are listed below.. but non of them seem to work when we try calling from external app. it gives cors error
[List all public packages in the npm registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251633/list-all-public-packages-in-the-npm-registry)