# how can i install all npm packages in to 'node_modules' folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I would like to install all npm packages. I don't mean to install the dependencies inside the package.json. I just want a fresh copy of all the packages in NPM. Means I would like to download all packages inside the 'node_modules' folder. This is to use the same packages for all projects where I will point all project's node_moduels to a single directory where i can use all the packages. Hopes someone can help me on it.  Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you write your question in more detail with proper explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @HirenF npm install <package>. The above code is only installs a certain package. I need complete packages in the NPM. Hopes you understood

Comment: npm is a huge library, to be downloaded in local. 
I think you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251633/list-all-public-packages-in-the-npm-registry) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

to install module locally use this :

```
 npm install PACKAGE
```

if you want to use package json you need to register all your package in to the dependency then run npm install. for example :

in package.json file:

```
   "dependencies": {

    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",

    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",

    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",

    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",

   "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",

   "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",

    "axios": "^0.27.2",

    "react": "^18.2.0",

    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",

    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  },
```

Comment: your code only installs a certain package. I would like to install all the package available in the NPM

Comment: right, i think you need to use package.json

Comment: ok, let me know how can i use package.json to install all NPM packages

Comment: you could introduce all your package in package.json (dependency) then  use npm install command and by default all module in dependency will be install

Comment: ok, Thank You for your comments. But i am still looking for a solution where i can install complete NPM package in a single command

Comment: good luck, anyway you can use this address : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255549/discussion-between-shaijuelayidath-and-tamy-ak).

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not all that clear.. myself and my wife tried to simulate from from what i gathered in your question... You want to download all npm packages without installing them as dependencies in a specific project.. right?

Well you can use the npm pack command to create a .tgz tarball for each package. Then, you can extract these tarballs into a shared directory that you can use for multiple projects.

So basically, take these baby steps to achieve this:

Create a directory where you want to store the downloaded packages -- this should be easy naa. For example, you can create a directory named shared-packages:

you can use commands like

**mkdir shared-packages
cd shared-packages**

Then you can also list all the packages you want to download. You can use npm ls to list all the packages currently installed in your project:

**i use commands like **npm ls --depth=0 --json | jq -r '.dependencies | keys[]' > package-list.txt****

As you can see, this command will create a package-list.txt file containing the names of all the top-level packages in your project.

you can then loop through the packages in package-list.txt and use npm pack to create tarballs for each package and move them to the shared-packages directory with something like this:

**while read -r package; do
npm pack "$package"
mv "$package"*.tgz ./
done < package-list.txt**

This will create .tgz files for each package in the shared-packages directory.

Now, you can use these tarballs in your other projects. To install a package from one of these tarballs, use the npm install command with the file path to the tarball. For example

**npm install /path/to/shared-packages/package-name-version.tgz**

Replace **/path/to/shared-packages/** with the actual path to your shared-packages directory and **package-name-version.tg**z with the name of the package you want to install.

Try this and let me know how it goes..

I hope this was helpful cheers!

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort for documenting the answer. I appreciate your effort. My question is pretty simple. You don't need to think too much. Just think that I need to download all packages of the NPM in to the 'node_modules' folder. Thats it. npm install <a single package name> // This is to install a certain package. I am looking for a command like following. npm install <all packages> Thats it. I'll do the rest of making the directory to use for other projects. But i'll check in detail your documentation for knowledge later. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).