# How to query npm API for a multi-part Typescript package?

Tags: python, api, npm, package

Currently developping an autobuild for the docker image of [slidev](https://github.com/slidevjs/slidev) hosted at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/stig124/slidev), I need to compare already built version with npm available version of the module

I have this code :

```py
import requests as curl


def getreleasegh():
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/slidevjs/slidev/tags"
    with curl.get(url) as r:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            j = r.json()
    release = j[0]['name']
    release.replace("v", "")
    return release


def getactualimage():
    url = 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/stig124/slidev/tags/'
    with curl.get(url) as r:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            j = r.json()
    image = j['results'][0]['name']
    return image
```

The npm package I want to query the version is `@slidev` with every subpackages being the same version tag

I used `npms.io` API from a suggestion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34071621/11478363)

Is there any way to query subpackages?

Querying API endpoint for any subpackages (`https://api.npms.io/v2/package/@slidev-cli`) return

```json
{"code":"INVALID_PARAMETER","message":"name can only contain URL-friendly characters (\"@slidev-cli\")"}
```

Querying `https://api.npms.io/v2/package/slidev-cli` returns

```json
{"code":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Module not found"}
```

Is there any way is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found a workaround by using the search function

I search for `slidev` using `https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=slidev` then process the first entry by finding if the package `scope` is the name of the parent package (the one with the `@`) if it isn't I jump to next entry and so on, and it works great

```py
def checknpm():
    base = 'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q='
    package = 'slidev'
    url = base + package
    with curl.get(url) as r:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            j = r.json()
    for i in range(5):
        if package in str(j['results'][i]['package']['scope']):
            npm = str(j['results'][i]['package']['version'])
            break
```